# Executing a ruby file

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run the following Git but am struggling because I don't have a great understanding of Ruby.

https://gist.github.com/tobi/9a60840ea2cf4d524d3aab56efff58a5

I've set the environmental variables.

I've set [valid output directory] to be the appropriate directory '.../desktop/notes'

```
STDERR.puts "#{File.basename(__FILE__)} [valid output directory]"
```

When I run ruby kindle.rb (the file name in the right directory), I get:

```
kindle.rb [valid output directory]
```

What am I missing here?

What is:

```
output_dir = if ARGV[0].nil? or !File.directory?(ARGV[0])
```

doing?

If I just change that chunk to:

```
output_dir = '.../kindle'
```

Everything works alright - Why do I need the other chunk of code?

Comment: Just to make sure, how're you running the script?

Comment: Using the command 'ruby kindle.rb'

Comment: @simplesam : The output you get on STDERR looks reasonable to me. It prints exactly what it is supposed to, since your ARGV is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script expects the directory path to be passed as an argument.

```sh
ruby kindle.rb <directory-path>
```

> What is:
>
> ```
> output_dir = if ARGV[0].nil? or !File.directory?(ARGV[0])
> ```
>
> doing?

`ARGV` contains the arguments passed to the script. The condition checks if the 1st argument is `nil` or if it is not a directory. If that's the case, it exits writing a help message to `STDERR`. Otherwise, it sets the `output_dir` variable to the return value of `File.expand_path(ARGV[0])`.

Comment: Oh my... Yeah, I feel pretty stupid and should have got here quicker. Good clarification and thank you

Comment: @simplesam No worries.